# Can Python Unittest Return the single test's result code?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to use unittest to automate a test case.  However, when the test passes or fails, it would write the result to the console.  Is there any way I can have unittest return some test result status code?  This is because I would like to add another function in my test script to record the test result into our database.  What is the best way to assess the test passed or failed programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on how much information you need about the test results. If you just want to know if the test passed/failed using [`unittest.main`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) :

> "By default main calls sys.exit() with an exit code indicating success
>   or failure of the tests run"

So checking the return value (0=passed, non-0=failed) of your test script is enough to get a passed/failed answer.

If you need more details about the tests, you can skip the `unittest.main()` call and call the `TestRunner.run` method directly which returns a [`TestResult`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult) object describing the results. An example:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TextTestRunner

class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_pass(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, 'Expected 1 to equal 1')

    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, 'uh-oh')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestExample)
    test_result = TestRunner().run(test_suite)
```

... and you can now inspect the `test_result` variable to get more details about the test run:

```
>>> test_result.testsRun
2
>>> test_result.failures
[(<test_example.TestExample testMethod=test_fail>, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "test_example.py", line 9, in test_fail\n    self.assertEqual(1, 2, \'uh-oh\')\nAssertionError: uh-oh\n')]
>>> len(test_result.failures)
1
```

The properties of `TestResult` are documented [here](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult), and examples & options for running the test runner is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html).

Comment: Yes, all I need is the exit code but how can I check it when after calling unittest.main() which then calls the exit code?

Comment: ' test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Example)
    test_result = TextTestRunner().run(test_suite)
print 'exit code:', unittest.main.sys.exit() Ran 1 test in 0.008s

FAILED (failures=1)
# of tests run: 1
exit code:
'

Comment: The exit code only applies if you run the unit test using `unittest.main()` in the '_\_main_\_' function in which case it is the value returned to whatever called your tests (i.e. the shell). You should not call `sys.exit()` yourself. If you want to run the test using the test runner, just check if test_results contains any errors.

Comment: Where is `TestRunner` defined?